# Error when adding a timeout command to while loop in bash

Tags: bash, timeout, command

So my while loop works fine, but when I add the timeout command it gives me this error:

```
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `do'
```

Here is the command:

```
timeout 30s while [ $? = 0 ]; do kill -0 $MYPID 2>/dev/null; if [ $? = 0 ]; then echo The Process PID is running && date +%r; else echo the Process PID is NOT running && date +%r; fi; done
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bash sees this: you want to execute the command `timeout` with arguments `30s`, `while`, `[`, `$?`, `=`, `0` and `]`. Then (because of the `;`) you want to execute `do ...`.

When bash parses your line, it complains about the `do` keyword that's not in a legal construct here… it's unexpected!

For a quick fix, wrap your commands like so:

```
timeout 30s bash -c 'while ....'
```